# Can foreach architecture be modified?

Tags: php, foreach

This is a strange question, but it's interesting so I thought I'd ask. Let's say I don't like how php's `foreach` loop operates and I always use it in the format, where all I did is added a counter outside and used it inside the `foreach` loop to tell if we're in the last element.

```
$counter = 1;
$array_size = count($array);
foreach($array as $item){
   //code
   if($counter == $array_size){ 
      $isLast = true 
   } else {
      $isLast = false; 
   }
   $counter++; 
}
```

My question is: can I override or fork or inherit (or whatever you want to call that) the original php foreach loop to include this new ability, so that I can now do this, without the need for initializing the counter and such.

```
newforeach($array as $item){
   //code
   $isLast = //something that returns true/false;
}
```

It's an interesting idea, so I wonder if one of the hardcore php guys here can somehow make this possible? or this sort of modification way too complicated without hacking the language itself?!

Comment: By definition, surely, changing the way a language control structure works requires "hacking the language itself"

Comment: What about [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943719/in-foreach-islastitem-exists)?

Comment: To at least make it prettier you could do `$isLast = ($counter == $array_size);`

Comment: @Gumbo Not totally obsolete. The idea of modifying default structures is still kind of interesting. I won't need it for this one, but you never know, it might come in handy later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is simply "can you override the implementation of php's language constructs" the answer is no. This is a feature of other dynamic langauges like [Javascript](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/) or Ruby often referred to as [Monkey Patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) or Duck Punching.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a class that wraps the array you're iterating over (you'll need to have it implement the [Iterator interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)) with an isLast() method which performs this check for you.

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
$arrayIterator = new MyArrayIterator($myArray);

foreach ($arrayIterator as $item)
{
  if ($arrayIterator->isLast())
  {
    doStuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: [The CachingIterator has a `hasNext` method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804599/adding-a-char-to-all-array-items-ap-art-from-last-using-for-foreach/4804812#4804812), so you can simply wrap the `ArrayIterator` into it. But +1 for suggesting Iterators.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a strange way to do things. Why not just have something like so:

```
$isLast = FALSE;
foreach( $array as $count => $item )
{
    $isLast = ($count+1 == count($array))
}
```

I'm sure someone else can clean that code up, it's been a while since I wrote PHP.

Alternatively, if you like your way of doing it, why not just put your if/then/else into a function say `isLast`, and call it like so:

`$isLast = isLast($item, $array)`

Comment: There's a few solutions to zmol's problem in his previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943719/in-foreach-islastitem-exists - your's won't work for associative arrays, or arrays where the key numbers aren't sequential (perhaps after a sort) and aren't missing any entries (no unsets or similar)

Comment: @Mark Baker: Good point on the sequential keys. I assumed he wasn't working with an associative array, seeing as he didn't use the keys himself. And apologies for not seeing his previous question.

Comment: no apologies necessary... I was just pointing you to a number of alternative solutions that don't all suffer from sequential-only syndrome

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your foreach to a while loop and iterate through the items using next(), like so:

```
$array = array('a' => 'hi', 2 => 2515, 'as' => 'foo');
while (true) {
    $item = current($array);
    echo $item, "\n";
    if (!next($array)) {
        echo '^last item!';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it (without modifying the syntax):

```
function foreach_counter($ar, $callback) {
  $counter = 1;
  $array_size = count($ar);
  foreach($ar as $item){
    $callback($item, $counter, $counter == $array_size);
    $counter++; 
  }
}

foreach_counter(array('a','b'), function($item, $counter, $isLast) {
     echo $counter . ': ' . $item . '' . ($isLast ? 'END' : ',');
});
// outputs 1: a, 2: b END
```

However, as you can see, it becomes harder to read the succinct version, so although you can, you shouldn't do it - especially as long as you're just beginning to understand php.

Oftentimes, you want to build a string in such a loop. Use `implode` for that:

```
echo implode(', ', array(1,2,3));
// output: 1, 2, 3
```